# Multiple image folders joining in google colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to work on  a computer vision model but the dataset is completely new to me. It is as shown :
[Dataset folders image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xLo1.png)

I have to extract each image in every folder and combine them into one train and one test folder. This is to get the filepaths of each image which I will use to decode jpeg. Can someone help me with the same ? Basically I need the filepaths of each image in one list. But the image names are also duplicate in each folder.

Comment: please take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.